# Oracle SQL: One query two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following base query:

```
SELECT INIT,TIDSPUNKT,AKTIVITETSTYPE 
   FROM ExampleDB.SAFE_DATA_VP_KR 
   WHERE DATO = '2020-05-25' AND
         AKTIVITETSTYPE = 'Udg¿ende/Produktion' AND
         INIT IN (SELECT initialer
                    FROM ExampleDB.SAFE_DATA_MEDARBEJDER
                    WHERE STATUS IN (1) AND
                          MED_STEDKODE_ID IN (5530) AND
                          ROLE_ID NOT IN (4)) 
   ORDER BY INIT, TIDSPUNKT;
```

I want to modify it and add a ACTIVITY_ID != 53 like the following, but it wont work.

```
SELECT INIT, TIDSPUNKT,AKTIVITETSTYPE 
  FROM ExampleDB.SAFE_DATA_VP_KR 
  WHERE DATO = '2020-05-25' 
  AND AKTIVITETSTYPE = 'Udg¿ende/Produktion' AND
      INIT IN (SELECT initialer 
                 FROM ExampleDB.SAFE_DATA_MEDARBEJDER 
                 WHERE STATUS IN (1) AND
                       MED_STEDKODE_ID IN (5530) AND
                       ROLE_ID NOT IN (4)) AND
      INIT IN (SELECT initialer 
                 FROM ExampleDB.SAFE_DATA_VAGTPLAN 
                 WHERE AKTIVITET_ID != 53) 
  ORDER BY INIT, TIDSPUNKT;
```

Comment: Please format your query so its not all on one line. And what does "it wont work." mean?

Comment: It wont actually remove the activity id 53 from the result of the SELECT query.

Comment: Moreover, sample dataset needed in order to be able to answer.

Comment: Hi, Although, sample data would be useful but  you can try following query as well select tmp.INIT, tmp.TIDSPUNKT, tmp.AKTIVITETSTYPE
  from ExampleDB.SAFE_DATA_VP_KR tmp
INNER JOIN ExampleDB.SAFE_DATA_MEDARBEJDER tmp1 ON tmp1.initialer = tmp.init 
                        AND tmp1.Status = 1
                        AND tmp1.MED_STEDKODE_ID in (5530)
                   and ROLE_ID not in (4))
INNER JOIN ExampleDB.SAFE_DATA_VAGTPLAN tmp2 ON tmp2.initialer = tmp.init 
                      AND tmp2.AKTIVITET_ID != 53
  order by tmp.INIT, tmp.TIDSPUNKT

Comment: Hello Rajat, this gives me an SQL error ORA-00933 SQl command has not been finished correctly

Comment: The  ORA-00933 for @RajatJaiswal's query is due to a stray extra bracket after `not in (4)`. (Comments aren't a great place for code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want `NOT IN` to filter out any `init` values that have the 53 activity:

```
and init not in (Select initialer
                 from ExampleDB.SAFE_DATA_VAGTPLAN
                 where AKTIVITET_ID = 53
                )
```

Note:  I strongly discourage the use of `NOT IN` with subqueries because they do not handle `NULL` values correctly.  You should rewrite this using `NOT EXISTS` -- after you have given your tables references appropriate aliases and qualified all column references.

Comment: Almost correct. I actually want the NOT IN to filter out any AKTIVITET_ID value with the value 53..